resizing terminal reprints prompt
ok, I know yall hate videos, and pictures, but I don't know how to describe the problem clearly.
When I resize the terminal, it reprints the prompt. Again and again. I've never seen this non-sense before.
On Ubuntu Mate 22.04
The Terminal is mate-terminal
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUjO1yLxEio

prompts longer than the window size seems to trigger the event.

It could have something to do with this. The bug is old, but never closed, and going by the explanation, is not in VTE-based terminals, but it's due to how the shell reacts. You can try and disable rewrap-on-resize from Dconf-editor, if you have the option available.

I looked all around in /org/mate/terminal for rewrap-on-resize but saw nothing like that. (in all the sub sections too.)
